# C++ and Eigen: How do I handle this 1x1 matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

Consider this excerpt:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 600*100*100; i++) {
    ( 1 / 2 * (1 - a) / a *   x.transpose() * y * (z + (1 - a) *
     z.transpose() * y(i) / z.sum() ) * x.transpose() * z );
}
```

In the code above, `x`, `y`, `z` are objects of the class `MatrixXd` in `Eigen` and `a` is a `double`. Through these multiplications, eventually the outcome is a scalar. The entire forloop took less than a second.

However, if I change my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 600*100*100; i++) {
    F(i) = F(i) + ( 1 / 2 * (1 - a) / a *   x.transpose() * y * (z + (1 - a) * 
          z.transpose() * y(i) / z.sum() ) * x.transpose() * z );
}
```

The forloop then takes 6 seconds. `F` is an `ArrayXd`. I'm trying to update each element of `F` through a loop and in each iteration I would do a series of simple matrix multiplications (which would result in a scalar).

I'm not sure what's wrong. How can I speed it up? I tried to use `.noalias()` but that didn't help. This could have to do with the fact that the outcome of the series of matrix multiplication results in a 1x1 `MatrixXd` and `Eigen` is having issues adding a `MatrixXd` to a number.

**Update**
Per @mars, I tried `eval()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 600*100*100; i++) {
    ( 1 / 2 * (1 - a) / a *   x.transpose() * y * (z + (1 - a) *
     z.transpose() * y(i) / z.sum() ) * x.transpose() * z ).eval();
}
```

And it takes ~6 seconds as well. Does that mean there's no way to optimize?

Also, I used `-O3`to compile.

Comment: Technically speaking, the outcome of all the multiplications in the first loop is not a scalar but an `Eigen::Product<...>` object that holds all the information that is needed to do the actual math and is convertible to a scalar. In the first loop you discard that object without evaluating it, which skips the calculation. What execution speed do you get if you call the method `.eval()` on the expression in the first loop?

Comment: I don't get your code. If z is a `MatrixXd`, then z(i) is a double, and 
`z(i).transpose()` makes no sense. Please make sure your code snippet is correct and reproductible. Also, please clarify the sizes of all objects. Last but not least, as mars said, the first code snippet does not compute anything. The entire loop should be removed by the compiler optimizations (`-O3`) if you use Eigen 3.x.

Comment: @ggael I made a typo.

Comment: @mars updated regarding `eval()`

Comment: @tryingtosolve it still does not make sense, z seems to be square because you have `z+z.transpose()`, but if the result is a scalar then z must also be a vector... Also please add the size of each matrix. To start with the optimizations:  if one matrix is a vector, then use a `VectorXd`. Then move all constant computations like `z.sum()` outside the loop. Also enable AVX/FMA with `-march=native`.

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve], instead of verbally describing the types and contents of your variables. Offtopic: If `a` is a double (and finite and not 0), then ` 1 / 2 * (1 - a) / a == 0.0` -- maybe you acually want `0.5`, instead of `1/2`